# .net core mvc model property type datetime cannot bind in AJAX Post request

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a model with a property with type DateTime. When I send an AJAX post request, the controller says the modelstats is invalid. Because it cannot parse the datetime. Im sending the datetime in this format "dd/mm/yyyy". I already set the culture and my aspnet.core project gives the correct format. Also, when I post using an razor form to with the same datetime format. It says modelstate is valid.

This is the date format im trying to pass: `23/06/2019`

My model:

```cs
public class Article
    {
        public Guid ArticleID { get; set; }
        public int ArticleRecordId { get; set; }
        public string ArticleMainBackGround { get; set; }
        public string ArticleMainBanner { get; set; }
        public string MainTitle { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? PublishFrom { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? PublishTo { get; set; }
        public int OrderSquence { get; set; }
    }
```

my ajax post request

```js
var payload = {
        ArticleRecordId : 0,
        ArticleMainBackGround: $("#ArticleMainBackGround").val(),
        ArticleMainBanner: $("#ArticleMainBanner").val(),
        MainTitle: $("#MainTitle").val(),
        PublishFrom: $("#StartDate").val() ,
        PublishTo: $("#EndDate").val() ,
        //OrderSquence: $("#OrderSquence").val(),
        IsEnabled: $("#IsEnabled").val(),
        ArticleSections: articleSection
    };
    console.log(payload);

    $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Article/AddArticle',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            failed: function () {
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Check IF Element having "#EndDate"  as ID contain name property like name="PublishTo" ? @superthomas

Answer (score 0):

Check IF Element having "#EndDate" as ID contain name property like name="PublishTo" ?